# How can I cancel a pending payment in App Store?

Tags: ios-appstore

I have accidentally subscribed yearly to an app, and now I removed the subscription but they're still trying to take the payment (no sufficient funds). Can I cancel the payment anyhow?

Answer (score 2):

If you cancelled the subscription soon after you subscribed, and you explain it was an accident no payment should be taken.

Bear in mind that if you had a free trial before the subscription, and you don't cancel 24 hours before the end of the free trial, you may still be charged.

> Some subscriptions might offer a discounted or free trial. If you don’t cancel more than 24 hours before your renewal date, your subscription might renew.

([Source](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT202039#subscriptions))

Make sure you follow [View, change, or cancel your subscriptions](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT202039#subscriptions).

Additionally, you can go to Apple's official [Report a Problem.](https://idmsa.apple.com/IDMSWebAuth/signin?appIdKey=6f59402f11d3e2234be5b88bf1c96e1e453a875aec205272add55157582a9f61&language=GB-EN) This is specifically for subscriptions.